# Postfix and JavaMail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

Tried sending JavaMail with Postfix installed on my Ubuntu pc.
It seems as though the mail is sent but it never arrives.
I just installed Postfix and have no idea how to configure it as an smtp server.

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false
220 UsProg.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "localhost", port: 25

EHLO eitan-pc
250-UsProg.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "VRFY", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<avicohen974631@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:<eitan.lp@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   *******@gmail.com
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Date: Sun, 17 May 2015 23:23:26 +0300 (IDT)
From: avicohen974631@gmail.com
To: *********@gmail.com
Message-ID: <2064112929.0.1431894206597.JavaMail.eitan@eitan-pc>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?16DXmdeh15nXldefINei150g16TXqNeV16fXodeZ?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

15TXldeT16LXlCDXlteQ16og16DXqdec15fXlCDXk9eo15og16nXqNeqINeQ16DXldeg15nXnteZ
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 99611E18F1
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Mail sent to '********@gmail.com' from avicohen974631@gmail.com
Task complete. 1 mails in 0 seconds
```

Comment: Check the postfix log to see if there are any errors, and if none, check the Gmail *spam* mailbox. Gmail doesn't like mail from unidentified sources and usually sends it directly to the spam.

Comment: could this just be that GMail is blocking the transfer, I used JavaMail for my web-app and needed to enable 'Allow less secure apps' in Gmail options?